# C# Falta alguna conversion?

Tags: c#, consola

Se supone que una persona ingresa una linea de caracteres por teclado separadas por un espacio en blanco seguido de otra linea de caracteres, el programa deberia indicar si los caracteres que estan separados por el espacio en blanco tienen la misma cantidad por ejemplo (asd sad).Creo que el planteamiento que hize esta bien pero por alguna razon no funciona...

el output que obtengo al ingresar por teclado (asd asd) es el else, ademas de esto tambien obtengo

> System.IndexOutOfRangeException en esta línea `if (var1[cont] == ' ')`

**Este es mi código**

```
        string var1;
        int num1;

        var1 = Console.ReadLine();
        for (int cont = 0; cont <= var1.Length; cont++)
        {
            if (var1[cont] == ' ')
            {
                num1 = cont + 1;
                if (((var1.Length - 1) - num1) == num1)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("son simetricos");

                }
                else
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("no son simetricos");
                }


            }


        }

        Console.WriteLine(var1.Length);
        Console.ReadKey();
```

Es verdad pude entender esa parte cada vez que entraba al primer IF en algun momento cuando cumplia la condicion teniendo en cuenta q se empieza de 0 y que Length nos da la cantidad de elementos, entra al IF y compara un elemento OutRange.

Pero por algun motivo sigo sin poder entrar al segundo IF, creo que no esta realizando las operaciones q le indico o algun termino no tiene el tipo de dato correcto..

Alguien mas abajo dijo que tendria que quitar cont+1 pero creo que no es asi debido a que cont es igual subindice que estoy recorriendo por ejemplo ingreso (A B) A es indice 0 si hago cont +1 digo que hay un caracter despues de esto al total de cracteres le resto 1 por q 1 es el espacio en blanco eso me da el total de caracteres sin el espacio en blanco , bueno ahora solo tengo restarle a ese total cont+1, si esa resta es igual a cont+1 entonces son iguales o simetricos

Comment: El error es porque intentas acceder a un indice fuera **(mayor)** del arreglo , Intenta modificar la condición del for `for (int cont = 0; cont < var1.Length; cont++)`

Comment: @Shiki, Si alguna respuesta te sirvió seria bueno que la marcaras como correcta, para que otras personas puedan accederla mas fácilmente y además para que la comunidad te siga ayudando con tus dudas.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Las corrección de arriba son correctas, también tené en cuenta que no debes sumarle uno a const

```html
 num1 = cont + 1;
```

Ya que siempre te dará como resultado que "no son simétricos"

Comment: Alguien mas abajo dijo que tendria que quitar cont+1 pero creo que no es asi debido a que cont es igual subindice que estoy recorriendo por ejemplo ingreso (A B) A es indice 0 si hago cont +1 digo que hay un caracter despues de esto al total de cracteres le resto 1 por q 1 es el espacio en blanco eso me da el total de caracteres sin el espacio en blanco , bueno ahora solo tengo restarle a ese total cont+1, si esa resta es igual a cont+1 entonces son iguales o simetricos

Comment: Pongamos como ejemplo (A B): Cuando se cumpla la condición si el caracter es vacio, el indice de iteración sería de valor 1, ahora bien esto quedaría siendo `num1  =  1 + 1` por lo cual estarías asumiendo que la primera parte contiene 2 caracteres en vez de uno. Y el el calculo que esta en el if quedaría asi `If( (3(Length)  - 1 )  - 2 ) == 2`.  En vez de   `If( (3(Length)  - 1 )  - 1 ) == 1`

Comment: Otra forma de planear el problema en caso de que lo desees sería utilizando el Split.  `var split = var1.Split(' ');
            if (split.Count() == 2) {
                if (split[0].Length == split[1].Length)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("son simetricos");
                }
                else
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("no son simetricos");
                }
            }else {Console.WriteLine("Solo se permite el uso de un caracter separador(' ')");}`

Comment: AHH!! dios estuve confundiendo un indice todo el tiempo,MUCHISIMAS GRACIAS!!!

Answer (score 1):

La Exception [IndexOutOfRangeException](https://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/system.indexoutofrangeexception(v=vs.110).aspx)  se produce cuando intentas acceder a un elemento del arreglo haciendo uso de un indice fuera del límite **(mayor)** o **menor**

Para solucionar este error bastaría con modificar la condición  de tu `for` ya que los indices inician desde **0** *(primer elemento)*  y **finalizan en (n-1)** *(último elemento)*

```
for (int cont = 0; cont < var1.Length; cont++)
```

**Update**

Con respecto a validar si son simétricos o no. podría probar esto.

```
if (var1[cont] == ' ')
{
   if (((var1.Length - 1) - cont) == cont) Console.WriteLine("son simetricos");
   else Console.WriteLine("no son simetricos");
   break;
}
```

Comment: Tenias razon en eso y lo entendi gracias, aparte de eso sigue el problema del segundo IF que indica  si son simetricos... no puedo entrar por ahi, agregue mas informacion sobre eso al tema principal.

Comment: @Shiki verificar mi actualización con respecto a su pregunta.

Answer (score 1):

Tú ciclo `for` debería estar de alguna de la siguientes formas:

```
for (int cont = 0; cont < var1.Length; cont++)
```

**O**

```
for (int cont = 0; cont <= var1.Length - 1; cont++)
```

Por ejemplo si tienes un arreglo con 10 ítems su índice mayor va a ser 9, ya que .NET todos los arreglos los maneja con los índices empezando en 0, entonces si usas `var1.Length (que para el ejemplo que te pongo seria igual a 10)` cuando el ciclo `for` llegue al ultimo recorrido vas a intentar acceder al índice 10, el cual no existe dentro del arreglo y por ende se va a presentar el error que te está ocurriendo.

Answer (score 1):

que tal algo así

```
  string var1 = Console.ReadLine();
        string[] separadores = { " " };

        string[] subCadenas = var1.Split(separadores, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
        if (subCadenas[0].Length == subCadenas[1].Length)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("son simetricos");
        }
        else {
            Console.WriteLine("no son simetricos");
        }
        Console.WriteLine(subCadenas[0].Length);
```

Comment: Gracias por tu aporte, Sayubu y bienvenido a Stack Overflow en Español. Por favor toma el [recorrido del sitio](http://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) y lee 
**[cómo escribo una buena respuesta](http://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)**. Esto es necesario para generar una **respuesta de calidad**.

Answer (score 1):

Por lo que entiendo lo que quieres hacer al fin y al cabo es que un usuario ingrese dos palabras distintas, y que el sistema le diga si tienen el mismo numero de letras cada una, sin importar cuales sean.

Hice un pequeño código que hace eso. Lo puedes probar en http://rextester.com/

```
//Rextester.Program.Main is the entry point for your code. Don't change it.
//Compiler version 4.0.30319.17929 for Microsoft (R) .NET Framework 4.5

using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

namespace Rextester
{
public class Program
{
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        //Your code goes here
        var temporal = Console.ReadLine();
    //Con la instrucción que esta abajo, separo las palabras por el espacio vacío que hay entre ellas y genero un arreglo.
        var palabras = temporal.Split(' ');

        //valido que sean al menos dos palabras 
        if(palabras.Length > 1){
            if(palabras[0].Length == palabras[1].Length){
                Console.WriteLine("Son iguales");
            }else{
                Console.WriteLine("No son iguales");
            }
        }else{
            Console.WriteLine("Debe ingresar por lo menos dos palabras.");
        }
    }
}
}
```

Haciendo ajustes en el código puedes colocar la cantidad de palabras que tu quieras y comparar cada una haciendo uso de un poco de imaginación:

```
//Rextester.Program.Main is the entry point for your code. Don't change it.
//Compiler version 4.0.30319.17929 for Microsoft (R) .NET Framework 4.5

using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

namespace Rextester
{
public class Program
{
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        //Your code goes here
        var temporal = Console.ReadLine();
        var palabras = temporal.Split(' ');

        //valido que sean al menos dos palabras 
        if(palabras.Length > 1){

            var numeroLetras = 0;
            bool iguales = true;
            foreach(string temp in palabras){
                if(numeroLetras != 0 && numeroLetras != temp.Length){
                    iguales = false;
                }
                numeroLetras = temp.Length;
            }

            if(iguales){
                Console.WriteLine("Todas las palabras tienen el mismo largo");
            }else{
                Console.WriteLine("Las palabras tienen distinto numero de letras.");
            }
        }else{
            Console.WriteLine("Debe ingresar por lo menos dos palabras.");
        }
    }
}
}
```

Así se ve en la pagina que te envié, para sacar el input, debes hacer click en el signo más que aparece como signo menos en la foto, donde esta el cursor.

[image: Ejemplo en la pagina que te coloqué más arriba.]

Espero haberle ayudado amigo. Saludos!